# Angularjs how to architect shared features on every page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I have recently started using angularjs and understand the basics. I have a project separated into separate angularjs apps - for example an account app, a mail app, a news app, etc. Each of these apps are its own angular module.

Now if I were to add a notification app and I wanted that notification app to run on every page in tandem with my other app for that specific page how should I architect my modules to do so?
*My main concern is that angular only allows for one ng-view so I cannot create one for my main app for that page and another for the notifications.

Comment: did you try specifying different apps for different elements on the same page? I am curious whether this would work.

Comment: @akonsu from the angular documentation: "Only one ngApp directive can be used per HTML document." It seems like angular is one app per page by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While each app currently only supports one ng-view, you can manually bootstrap as many applications as you want (each with its own ng-view) to different elements in the page with something like this:

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('main_container'), ['my-app']);
```

We combine it with jQuery to be able to know when it's been bootstrapped, and to add in an ng-controller as well:

```
$(function () {
    $('#main_container').attr('ng-controller', 'MainCtrl')
    $.when(angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('main_container'), ['my-app'])).done( function() {
        $('body').show()
    })
});
```

If you want to communicate between apps, then you need to do it with Angular's version of window: $window and events or a service as explained here: [Share a single service between multiple angular.js apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725392/share-a-single-service-between-multiple-angular-js-apps)

Comment: very cool! is there a specific reason as to why you need to wait for the app to be bootstrapped?

Comment: It prevents flicker and displays the whole page at once.

Comment: I marked this as the answer but I have some questions: if each module now has its own ng-view how exactly do I load html into each ng-view (since ng-view normally uses routing)? Also how exactly does routing work with multiple modules?

Comment: The downside to multiple apps, at least as far as I was able to determine, was that only one route could be active at any one time. This worked for us, because we had just one "master app".

Answer (score 0):

As Angular documentation says.

> The directive designates the root of the application and is typically
>   placed at the root of the page....ngApp is the easiest way to
>   bootstrap an application.

An angular app defines it's module but it can have dependency on other modules too. So your example for notification is a module dependency not a app dependency.

You would create module for notification like

```
var notificationModule=angular.module('notification', []);
```

and register multiple sub elements like controllers, directives, filters, services etc.

You would then add this module as dependency into other modules such as

```
var customerModule=angular.module('customer', ['notification']);
```

You can register the `notification` dependency with any module not just the module linked to `ng-app`.

You html structure should be such that the main view is contained in `ng-view` and the ancillary view are included using `ng-include` directive. Since `ng-include src` property supports data binding you can swap the templates used with `ng-include` when the main `ng-view` content changes.