# How to share $rootScope when manually bootstrapping with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating an app where I have two apps or `Divs`. One is bootstrapped using `ng-app` directive, while the other one, I'm manually bootstrap using `angular.bootstrap` method.

The thing is both these `divs` are using a `session` service which $broadcasts to `$rootScope`, but as you can see when you the `$rootScope` is not shared between apps.

So a `$rootScope.$broadcast` in `appB` is not caught by `appA`.

Here is a demo:

```js
angular.module('ngApp', [])
  .controller('ngAppController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.msg = "Waiting for message..";
    $scope.$on('YO', function() {
      $scope.msg = 'Message recd';
    });

    //$rootScope.$broadcast('YO');
  });


var bElement = document.querySelector('#appB');
angular.module('appB', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.msg = "Hello from app 'b'";
    $rootScope.$broadcast('YO');
  });
angular.bootstrap(bElement, ['appB']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="ngAppController">
  <div>{{msg}}</div>
</div>
<div id="appB">
  <div>{{msg}}</div>
</div>
```

**How can I make it so that I can catch broadcast from `appB` into `appA`?**

Comment: why not just create one instance of application on common parent element of these two divs?

Comment: I'm using a template in which the header template is fixed (checks user status). The body part is another template that is loaded with PHP and it contains it's own app. But the `session` service is common between two and since the header already loads the data in `session`, I want to share the two.

Comment: `window.postMessage` with `addActionListeners`would help you..

Comment: You might find [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725392/share-a-single-service-between-multiple-angular-js-apps) useful. It works by maintaining an array of `$rootScope`s on the window and notifying each when a change occurs in the service. I'm using a pattern like this for my most recent project, and it seems to work well.

Comment: would it make sense to keep a gobal array of `$rootScopes` inside the service and then send broadcast to each `$rootScope` individually?

Comment: @supersan Yep! That's exactly what's happening the first answer to the question I linked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure angular apps are not supposed to be aware of other angular apps on the page, so for this unusual case I would suggest building a "glue" application visible to both, e.g. `window.superAngularScope = {...}`. You could create whatever api you require in this object. However, unless you have a really good reason for violating encapsulation between the two angular apps, I'd advise you to find a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, you might need to use events outside of the angular framework, as separate angular modules don't share their `rootScope`.

You can use the `window` or `document` element to create [event listeners and custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), or use jQuery's `trigger` and `on`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `window.addEventListener`  with `window.postMessage` which do communication between two windows or on same window.

**Code**

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])
  .controller('ngAppController', function($scope, $rootScope, $window) {
    $scope.msg = "Waiting for message..";
    $scope.$on('YO', function() {
    //  $scope.msg = 'Message recd';
    //});
    $window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.msg = e.data;
      });
    });
    //$rootScope.$broadcast('YO');
  });

var bElement = document.querySelector('#appB');
angular.module('appB', [])
  .run(function($rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.msg = "Hello from app 'b'";
    //$rootScope.$broadcast('YO');
    $window.postMessage('YO', '*');
  });
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngApp']);
  angular.bootstrap(bElement, ['appB']);
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rre9RD0tUbEcb0ty3bdw?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the solution but a lot of application are already written and are using the `$scope.$on` code. Using the `message api` will require me to change a lot of code everywhere... i'm thinking it would be better to keep a global array of `$rootScope` in the session service and then send individual broadcast to each each one of them (haven't tested it yet)

Comment: are you sure the solution you made is work for you?? I doubt that.

Comment: hi, yes it is working.. i've posted a working demo of it below.. I basically needed the session service to broadcast to all $rootScopes and it is doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, and based on the replies I got here, this is working for me:

```js
(function() {
  var m = angular.module('session', []);
  var serviceInstance = null;
  var rootScopeArray = [];

  m.provider('$session', function() {
    this.$get = ['$q', '$http', '$timeout',  '$window', '$rootScope',
      function($q, $http, $timeout, $window, $rootScope) {
        rootScopeArray.push($rootScope);

        if (serviceInstance) {
          return serviceInstance;
        }

        $timeout(function(){
          for (var i = 0; i < rootScopeArray.length; i++) {
            rootScopeArray[i].$broadcast("YO");
          }
        }, 2000);
        
        return serviceInstance;
      }
    ];
  });

  return m;
})();

angular.module('ngApp', ['session'])
  .controller('ngAppController', function($scope, $session) {
    $scope.msg = "Waiting for message..";
    $scope.$on('YO', function() {
      $scope.msg = 'Message recd';
    });

    //$rootScope.$broadcast('YO');
  });


var bElement = document.querySelector('#appB');
angular.module('appB', ['session'])
  .run(function($rootScope, $session) {
    $rootScope.msg = "Hello from app 'b'";
    $rootScope.$on('YO', function() {
      $rootScope.msg = 'Message recd';
    });
  });
angular.bootstrap(bElement, ['appB']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="ngAppController">
    <div>{{msg}}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="appB">
    <div>{{msg}}</div>
  </div>
```

The solution seems to be working for my app and I didn't have to change any code. Just update the `session` service.

If there is a better way to do it, please do advise.