# How to watch variables in other controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, components, angularjs-components

I have a component called histogram demo in which there is a separate controller that has a variable called `$scope.selectedElements` and I want to watch this variable in the main `appCtrl` controller. How would I be able to access this variable without `$rootScope`.

Main HTML

```
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="histogram-test" ng-controller="appCtrl">

 <div  class="histogram-container"> <histogram-demo options = "options" data="data"></histogram-demo></div>
 </html>
```

App.JS

```
angular
.module('histogram-test')
.config(function ($httpProvider, usSpinnerConfigProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    usSpinnerConfigProvider.setDefaults({
        // see http://spin.js.org/
        color: 'white',
        radius: 30,
        width: 8,
        length: 16,
        shadow: true,
    });
})
.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, appConfig, $rootScope, auth, $state) {
/** HERE is where I want to watch $scope.selectedElements in Component.js **/}
```

Component.JS

```
angular
.module('histogram-test').component('histogramDemo', {
    bindings: {
        data: "=",
        options: "=",
    },
    templateUrl: templateUrl,
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
});

function controller($state, $scope) { ...
$scope.selectedElements = []; ...}
```

Comment: You can use event emitter which is better option.

Comment: how would i use an event emitter to send my array of objects to app.js?

Comment: Move the selectedElements list to a service and inject the service in both the component and controller. That works because services are singletons.

Comment: Since both cotroller are in different modules you need to use Shared service https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725874/5950377

Comment: @GavishiddappaGadagi They aren't in different modules.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen sorry i misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply consider passing a method to `component`, and call that method from component whenever you're changing `selectedElements`. Also for sec of make your application more performant follow one way data flow by making your bindings to use `<`(one way binding).

```
bindings: {
    data: "<",
    options: "<",
    selectedItemChange: '&'
},
```

and then your directive element will look like

```
<histogram-demo 
   options="options" 
   data="data" 
   selected-item-changed="itemChanged(items)">
</histogram-demo>
```

And whenever you changed `vm.selectedItems` variable inside controller component, do call `vm.selectedItemChange({items: vm.selectedItems})`, so the consumer of `histogram-demo` component will have method which will receive an `selectedItems` array.